# SQL compare multiple rows and get values based on percentage difference in same table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to compare the buy rates from same vendorid based on % and get the sell rate if all buy values are within 2% of the minimum buyrate. I am adding 5% to that buyrate. if one buy value goes above 2% then the used row value would be zero. And if the max buy value and the min buy value is less than 2% in difference then the sell value would be (max buyrate + 5%). please see the table below that I got from following select query.

```
SELECT distinct LOWER(vendors.tag), vendors.buyrate, ((buyrate *'0.05')+buyrate) AS midrate, (select distinct
min(midrate)) AS sellrate, vendors.ship, vendorid,  
used FROM vendors WHERE vendors.ship IN (9,0)   
order by vendorid
```

| LOWER(vendors.tag) | buyrate | midrate | sellrate | ship | vendorid | used |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| crna | 1.15 | 1.2075 | 1.2075 | 9 | 2 | 11 |
| crna | 1.17 | 1.2285 | 1.2285 | 9 | 2 | 12 |
| crna | 1.20 | 1.26 | 1.26 | 9 | 2 | 13 |
| prllc | 1.10 | 1.155 | 1.155 | 9 | 3 | 14 |
| prllc | 1.16 | 1.218 | 1.218 | 9 | 3 | 15 |
| wmllc | 1.32 | 1.386 | 1.386 | 9 | 4 | 16 |
| wmllc | 1.33 | 1.3965 | 1.3965 | 9 | 4 | 17 |
| wmllc | 1.34 | 1.407 | 1.407 | 9 | 4 | 18 |
| wmllc | 1.36 | 1.428 | 1.428 | 9 | 4 | 19 |

My goal is to get the following results :

| LOWER(vendors.tag) | buyrate | midrate | sellrate | ship | vendorid | used |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| crna | 1.15 | 1.2285 | 1.2285 | 9 | 2 | 11 |
| crna | 1.17 | 1.2285 | 1.2285 | 9 | 2 | 12 |
| crna | 1.20 | 1.26 | 1.26 | 9 | 2 | 0 |
| prllc | 1.10 | 1.155 | 1.155 | 9 | 3 | 14 |
| prllc | 1.16 | 1.218 | 1.218 | 9 | 3 | 0 |
| wmllc | 1.32 | 1.407 | 1.407 | 9 | 4 | 16 |
| wmllc | 1.33 | 1.407 | 1.407 | 9 | 4 | 17 |
| wmllc | 1.34 | 1.407 | 1.407 | 9 | 4 | 18 |
| wmllc | 1.36 | 1.428 | 1.428 | 9 | 4 | 0 |

Using 5.1.73 mysql version. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: it would hep if we can see the data that produce that result

Comment: i dont have the data because i couldnt get to that result. i was unable to compare buy rates

Comment: make a dbfiddle with all tables and inserted data, it is so very difficult to solve it

Comment: please check the link - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8t1Q8MWXenWSw3kC6iSat7/0

Comment: i rewrote your query, so that would make sense, but i rea d your text 5 times and still i don't get what you are searching for https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8t1Q8MWXenWSw3kC6iSat7/3

Comment: please take a look a the wmllc rows in results table. minimum buyrate is $1.32 out of 4. if you multiply that with 2% then we get 1.3464. we have 3 buyrate which falls under 1.3464 so we would take the max value between those 3 which is 1.34 and multiply that with 5%. that becomes the sell rate (1.407) for all 3 and since 1.36 is unused, its used column value becomes zero. hope you get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that you understand, MySQL can do almost anything but somethings anent't really the thing for MySQL

In general, you need to now what you want and then you have to thing aboput how do you get that information at every level

To understand that you need to understamd all subqueries and join that i made, to follow your idea.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE vendors (
>   vendors1 char(30) ,
>   buyrate decimal(10,5),
>   ship int(11) ,
>   vendorid int(30) ,
>   used int(11) 
>
> );
> INSERT INTO vendors ( vendors1, buyrate,  ship, vendorid, used) VALUES
> ('crna', 1.15, 9, 2, 11),
> ('crna', 1.17,  9, 2, 12),
> ('crna', 1.20,  9, 2, 13),
> ('prllc', 1.10,  9,3, 14),
> ('prllc', 1.16,  9, 3, 15),
> ('wmllc', 1.32,  9, 4, 16),
> ('wmllc', 1.33, 9, 4, 17),
> ('wmllc', 1.34,  9, 4, 18),
> ('wmllc', 1.36,  9, 4, 19);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> vendors1, buyrate,selrate,  ship, v2.vendorid, IF(FIND_IN_SET(buyrate ,sellunder),  used,0) as used
> FROM vendors v2
> INNER JOIN
> (SELECT vendorid,GROUP_CONCAT(buyrate) sellunder, MAX(buyrate)  * 1.05 selrate
> FROM
> (SELECT v.vendorid, buyrate FROM vendors v JOIN 
> (SELECT vendorid, MIN(buyrate) * 1.02  minbyrate FROM vendors GROUP BY vendorid) v1 
> ON v.vendorid = v1.vendorid
> WHERE v.buyrate < minbyrate) t2
> GROUP BY vendorid) v3 ON v2.vendorid = v3.vendorid
> ```
>
> ```
> vendors1 | buyrate |   selrate | ship | vendorid | used
> :------- | ------: | --------: | ---: | -------: | ---:
> crna     | 1.15000 | 1.2285000 |    9 |        2 |   11
> crna     | 1.17000 | 1.2285000 |    9 |        2 |   12
> crna     | 1.20000 | 1.2285000 |    9 |        2 |    0
> prllc    | 1.10000 | 1.1550000 |    9 |        3 |   14
> prllc    | 1.16000 | 1.1550000 |    9 |        3 |    0
> wmllc    | 1.32000 | 1.4070000 |    9 |        4 |   16
> wmllc    | 1.33000 | 1.4070000 |    9 |        4 |   17
> wmllc    | 1.34000 | 1.4070000 |    9 |        4 |   18
> wmllc    | 1.36000 | 1.4070000 |    9 |        4 |    0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7b66c8b1a11051ee7de9454967d8feb4)*

Comment: Where can I add the condition to show the value for only ship 9? Because there are over hundreds of ship IDs, thank you

Comment: see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=29f76d67ba986746952a3b1099a703e0

Comment: where can i set more condition that it will compare buyrate only from ship id 9 and not any other IDs in the table , otherwise results are as follows - please check.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=b158c358239452d4be3cc2cb1881c5aa

Comment: and please every further question nedds to be ask in a new question, that the rules here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=8a32b947bb2bc62e6b411a917a5b9eba